# what is the measurement of x and y In "action.moveByOffset(xOffset, yOffset)"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to test a website, when I use the code `action.moveByOffset(xOffset, yOffset);` what is the measurement of those x and y offsets? are they pixels or centimeters or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when Selenium accepts coordinates without specification of a unit, the coordinates are interpreted to be in pixels. Even though the documentation does not state it, I know it is so from having passed pixel coordinates to such functions and gotten the expected results.